# Finding text after a certain character

Tags: python

I want to find something after a certain character. I am aware of how to find something before using `rfind`, but not so sure of the syntax to find something after. Here is an example

```
text = 'Hello.world' 

#to find something before
print(text[:text.rfind('.')])
# out : 
Hello

# to find something after, I tried this, but of course it's incorrect
print(text[text:.rfind('.')])
```

Any ideas on how to use the syntax to find something after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(text[text.rfind('.')+1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Two other methods you may try might include splitting the string, and also doing a regex substitution to isolate the substring you want:

```
text = 'Hello.world'
print(text.split('.')[1])

print(re.sub(r'^.*\.', '', text))
```

Splitting would proabably outperform `re.sub` here, so I recommend `split()` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(text[text:.rfind('.')]) => print(text[text.find('.')+1:])
```

Here's another way to do it, str.partition and str.rpartition

```
def find(text, sep=' ', right=False):
    if not (text and sep) or sep not in text:
        return None
    return text.rpartition(sep)[2] if right else text.partition(sep)[0]

find('Hello.Word', '.')         # 'Hello'
find('Hello.Word', '.', True)   # 'Word'
```